# i started this replication wizard it adds GUID FIELD, how should i add data to this manually in future?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

using replication in sql srv causes the addition of this guid field, it also adds a value to it

but when i insert new records to the db, i have to give somthing or the guid field

it should be like aaaaa-aaa-something and unique!!

this is a problem for me , how am i supposed to do this keeping it unique every time?

should sql srv automatically add some yhing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ROWGUIDCOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) added by Merge Replication should be populated with... guids:

> ROWGUIDCOL does not enforce uniqueness
>   of the values that are stored in the
>   column and does not automatically
>   generate values for new rows that are
>   inserted into the table. **To generate
>   unique values for each column, either
>   use the NEWID function on INSERT
>   statements or specify the NEWID
>   function as the default for the
>   column**.